# Does Turing determinacy imply full determinacy?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, computability-theory, large-cardinals, descriptive-set-theory

The axiom of Turing determinacy is a weakening of the full axiom of determinacy, $AD$, in which only games with payoff sets which are $\equiv_T$-invariant are demanded to be determined.

In "Turing determinacy and the continuum hypothesis" (published in 1989), Ramez Sami writes:

> "The main question so far unsettled in this particular domain can be roughly put this way: is it true that for any "reasonable" pointclass $\Gamma$ we have: Turing-Det$(\Gamma)\implies$Det$(\Gamma)$? In particular is it the case that: [over $ZF+DC$, presumably] Turing $AD$ implies $AD$?"
>
> - http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01622874, page 153

My question is, what is the status of this question currently? Do we know whether Turing $AD$ is strictly weaker than $AD$? The only recent work I know of around Turing determinacy is from the reverse mathematical side ([http://www.math.cornell.edu/~shore/papers/pdf/TDet21.pdf](http://www.math.cornell.edu/%7Eshore/papers/pdf/TDet21.pdf)); I'm not at all familiar with the set theory on the subject.

(I vaguely recall that Turing determinacy implies that every Suslin set is determined, but I can't remember where I supposedly learned this "fact.")

Comment: It seems even unknown whether $TD$ implies the nonexistence of a Bernstein set.

Comment: I think this is no longer unknown : https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.12558

Comment: @PaulLarson Unless I'm missing something, that's specifically about the perfect set property - I don't see how to lift it to an equivalence between general determinacy principles, and in the intro at a glance they only claim to answer a special case of question $2$, not question $1$ itself.

Comment: @PaulLarson And in section IV they list that as a still-open problem.

Comment: I should have read it more carefully. I believe that that paper is not up to date, but I may be misinformed.

Comment: I think that it is still open.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is open. In $L(\mathbb R)$ the answer is yes. Hugh has several proofs of this, and it remains one of the few unpublished results in the area. The latest version of the statement (that I know of) is the claim in your parenthetical remark at the end. This gives determinacy in $L(\mathbb R)$ using, for example, a reflection argument.

(I mentioned this a while ago somewhere on this site. Maybe that's where you heard of it? This can be used to prove that $\omega$-board determinacy is equiconsistent with determinacy. I seem to recall that's how the topic came up.)

---

**Update** (Jun 25/22): Hugh has just published a proof that Turing determinacy implies the determinacy of Suslin sets (which gives $L(\mathbb R)$-determinacy and more). He indicates in the paper that the general question remains open. Coordinates:

> NEW ZEALAND JOURNAL OF MATHEMATICS
> Volume 52 (2022), 845–863, "Turing determinacy and Suslin sets"
> https://doi.org/10.53733/140

Comment: Based on your answer, I googled around and found this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656414/consistency-strength-of-turing-measurability. So that must be what I was remembering. It's probably too much to ask, but do you know if there is a version of the proof floating around?

Comment: I don't think so, unfortunately. Hugh lectured on this at the seminar at Berkeley a few years ago, but I couldn't find anybody who had taken notes.

Comment: (And, yes, you are right, it was on MSE that this came up.)

Answer (score 5):

To show this in L(R) (or any well understood determinacy model) one apparently has to run a core model induction as in section 6.2 of  https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/core_model_induction.pdf  which explains why it is open in the abstract.